# How to change theme for file viewer

Tags: file-browser, theme

I reset many colors individually using the Themes options. Now my file viewer looks weird. (The place you enter the name to save or find a file and the button to open or save.) I can't find a setting specifically to edit the theme colors for File Viewer. Does anyone know which ones affect it?

Comment: Hi. Which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: version: 2.81 (sub 16), branch: master, commit date: 2019-12-04 11:32, hash: f1aa4d18d49d, type: Release
build date: 2019-12-04, 14:30:40
platform: Windows

Comment: I was able to fix most things, but when opening or saving a file, as soon as I click on the name on the bar, to save as a new name, it goes all black.. I assume this is because somewhere the theme for selected items is set to a black background, since the text is already black. But I cannot find any place that has a setting for selected items which has black as the background. Any ideas? Once I start to edit the name by double clicking on black area, the black background goes away so then I can type as I need to do, but it is annoying, and I cant see what is there unless I start to change it.